# npm ERR! cb() never called! npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at: npm ERR

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

```
    npm ERR! cb() never called!
    
    npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
    npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/cli/issues>
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /home/abhijith/.npm/_logs/2021-05-12T16_20_42_200Z-debug.log
    
    Aborting installation.
      npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.
    
    Deleting generated file... package.json
```

**getting error trying to install react { npx react-create-app app}**

> i try sudo npm cache, sudo npm  cache --force clean but still getting same error

Comment: Make sure you're using the correct node version for the package you're installing

Comment: yes i use stable version if i delete node global and reinstall it work fine again, but some times go the same error came back!

Answer (score 2):

this is an error related to npm package and installing latest version of npm worked at me :

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem also got resolved after installing the latest version of npm. But I needed to use `sudo` before `npm install -g npm@latest`. Otherwise there were some warnings and errors of access denied.